# How do I track my blogpost number of shares on social media and have them show in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I am managing the web analytics of a wordpress blog. It has a plugin which gives the visitors share the blog on a number of social media. I wan to track how many of the users shred the blogpost and have the data show up in my google analytics.
Is this possible? What steps will I have to take to achieve this?

Comment: Its very possible that the plugin itself provides some sort of analytics, if not you can switch to one that does, there are plenty of them. For having it in Google Analytics, you can attach some click events on those links and they will show up in your analytics reports.

Comment: What plugin are you using? AddThis for example has analytics reporting with GA but only works with classic analytics. You need to do some custom coding for Universal Analytics but it is possible

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to use a plugin that specifically has that sort of analytics added as part of it or can throw an event to Google Analytics to detect the share. Short of that if all you want is lists on how often content has been shared and you don't care who has shared the content then most social networks have API's into their social graph that allows you to see the number of shares, likes, comments, etc, on a specific graph element including a web page URL.

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Tag Manager and set and fire a tag when user clicks on one of the share buttons.

Do not know which plugin you have, but I would suggest you use Click Element ID identifier.